# No errors and always zero for result

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to write a function that gets the average of a users number guesses. The table has the userID and tieBreakerPoints.

```
function getUserTBA($userID) {
    global $mysqli;

    // loop through user totals & calculate average for each user
    $sql = "SELECT u.userID, p.userID, AVG(p.tieBreakerPoints) AS 'avarage' ";
    $sql .= "FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "picksummary p";
    $sql .= "inner join " . DB_PREFIX . "users u on p.userID = u.userID ";    
    $sql .= "WHERE p.userID = " . $user->userID . " ";
    $sql .= "GROUP BY p.userID";
    $query = $mysqli->query($sql);

    if ($query->num_rows > 0) {
        $row = $query->fetch_array();
        return (int)$row['average'];
    }

    return 0;
}
```

When I call the function, I only seem to get zero values, but if I run the SQL query directly in SQL, I get the results. Am I missing something with this function?

Comment: Where is `DB_PREFIX` defined? Where is `$user` defined? Is this an independent function or a class method?

Comment: are you getting any warnings as well?

Comment: put `echo $mysqli->error;` before `return 0;` and tell us what it says

Comment: DB_PREFIX is used elsewhere and works, as does $user.. Here is the error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'GROUP BY p.userID' at line 1

Comment: That error could suggest that you are using MySQL 5.7 or newer wherein MySQL will throw an error (as it should) in the event that you don't include non-aggregated fields in your GROUP BY statement (if you are using pre-5.7 mysql, then check Don't Panic's answer below about the potential for a NULL userid, which would still cause this error regardless of version). Either aggregate `u.userid` with an aggregate function, or (probably more correctly) include it in your GROUP BY statement.

Comment: Also [see here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html) about potentially toggling your `only_full_group_by` setting for you database to false to have it act more like pre-5.7 where partial group by's were allowed.

Comment: @JNevill I may be mistaken, but I believe that would throw an error specific to that issue rather than a syntax error, wouldn't it? (I agree it's something that should be addressed regardless.)

Comment: @Don'tPanic Yes... I believe you are right. I padded my comment a bit after reading your very correct answer. I figured I'd leave the comment in place since it still may be helpful to some poor searcher in the future that stumbles onto this page.

Answer (score 1):

There may be other problems, but `$user` (and by extension, `$user->userID`) is undefined in your function scope. Consequently, you're concatenating a `null` value there, so the SQL you're generating is

```
WHERE p.userID =  GROUP BY p.userID
```

which is causing the error you mentioned in the comments. It's a syntax error because you have a keyword where it's expecting a value.

I see you have `$userID` as a parameter to the function, but it isn't used. Should it just be `$user`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure PHP to emit errors.

Your query creates a virtual column called 'avarage', but your php code uses the spelling 'average'. Turning on errors would have made this very obvious.

Comment: Good point! I did not notice the spelling error. But you're right, the PHP interpreter wouldn't have missed it.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I have corrected it, but does not resolve the issue.